# 64bit compilation of asp.net dllls

Tags: asp.net

We are having one problem while compiling with 64bit dlls. We are having lots of classlibray in our project and one webapplication. and when comiple it with x64 plateform with 32 bit operating system its compiling  but when we move that thing into production environment which is 64bit operating system then its giviing error that one of assambly is not able to load. Can any one have any idea for that? All the class library is also on comipleted x64 option.

Comment: please detail the full exception information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, so this is not really an answer, but I think it's worth mentioning.

Depending on what you are doing, some COM libraries and third-party Assemblies will require you to run on WOW64.  Try doing a fresh rebuild of all the components in your project, and instead of compiling for "Any CPU" compile for "x86" and deploy that.  This should force your assembly to run in 32-bit mode on WOW64, and therefore may make your third-party libraries happy.

Comment: +1 for specifically compiling to x86 (assuming that is an acceptable alternative).